# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) While using JSON package to parse JSON

Tags: python, json

Im trying to change a value in a JSON file, but it gives me an error when I run it, and I cant figure out why. Heres my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\BeatSaber.jl-master\src\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = json.load(f)
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Kyle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

And Heres my code:

```
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as f:
  data = json.load(f)

data["_songAuthorName"] = "jfosenoi"

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
  data = json.dump(f)
```

My JSON is created by a program that I made that's not Python, but here it is:

```
{
  "_version": "2.0.0",
  "_songName": "<SongName>",
  "_songSubName": "",
  "_songAuthorName": "",
  "_levelAuthorName": "Kyle Buchanan",
  "_beatsPerMinute": 60,
  "_songTimeOffset": 0,
  "_shuffle": 0,
  "_shufflePeriod": 0,
  "_previewStartTime": 2,
  "_previewDuration": 0,
  "_songFilename": "song.egg",
  "_coverImageFilename": "cover.jpg",
  "_environmentName": "DefaultEnvironment",
  "_difficultyBeatmapSets": [
    {
      "_beatmapCharacteristicName": "Standard",
      "_difficultyBeatmaps": [
        {
          "_difficulty": "ExpertPlus",
          "_difficultyRank": 9,
          "_beatmapFilename": "ExpertPlus.dat",
          "_noteJumpMovementSpeed": 0,
          "_noteJumpStartBeatOffset": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: looks like `f` is `None`

Comment: When I have it print f, I get this:
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='data.json' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>

Comment: maybe you should check your path.

Comment: data.json is in the same folder as the Python program.

Comment: Youre leaving something out of the question. Your code and json work fine. it looks like youre using `text IO` which a quick google says *Text I/O expects and produces str objects*

Comment: Print the file contents before trying to parse them as JSON. If it prints, you have an invalid character in your JSON, possibly an invisible one.

Comment: Yeah I think @JaredSmith might be right there - encoding cp1252 is micosoft encoding which can mess things up. `"` being one of those things.

Comment: @Hootyfox - if you replace the json in your file directly with the json in your question, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("data.json", "w") as f:
  data = json.dump(f)
```

This is wrong,

Try this:

```
with open("data.json", "w") as f:
  json.dump(data, f)
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump